# Email Additional To list like show "All co-workers in company"

Tags: email, standard

This small change could help our users quite a lot but i fear it isn't possible with standard salesforce functionality.  When clicking to send an email through standard salesforce functionality you are offered the "Additional To" search.  On selecting this it allows a list view of "All Co-workers in Company" that displays our users.

Is it possible to create another list view filtering out specific roles/profiles of our users

Ultimately we have hundreds and hundreds of users and want to make it easier for a user to select from the list. Our roadmap of development includes a custom VF/Apex class to redesign this functionality but it isn't planned soon so had hoped for a quick fix.  I haven't been able to find anything related on Google or setup just yet.

Thanks

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, as an administrator, you should be able to create custom list views (Classic) that will give different views to select from that would have different filters applied to them, depending on the fields available in the view to filter on. I don't know what page you're sending the email from, so can't necessarily guide further, but most list views are configurable like that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a standard email sending option, then usually the CC Text Area refers the account's related contact details, there is no way to configure is to take the contact details from other account.
Said that, the only possible workaround to this would be to inject the CC values using the URL hack.
To achieve that you will have to create a custom button (and select URL), that would replicate the present send email button. For details please see [this](http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-email-url-hack-tutorial/)

The custom button URL for opportunity will look below

- p3_lkid – Related To
- retURL – Return URL if cancel is pressed
- p2_lkid – To (Contact or Lead ID)
- p4 – CC
- p5 – BCC
- p6 – Subject
- p23- Email Body
- p24 – Additional To
- template_id – Salesforce Email Template ID

As a prerequisite I would always add in p3_lkid and retURL as these will always be needed.

/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}&retURL={!Opportunity.Id}